# WPF WF4.5 Rehosted Designer Memory Issues

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, memory-leaks, workflow-foundation-4

I have recently developed a WPF application that re hosts a Workflow Designer with some custom activities.
I faced a memory issue (Out Of Memory Exception) after the following scenario: I opened an old workflow with more than 150 activity and I started modifying all of them (open a window, modify some data, save and close the window) until the exception occurred.
At this stage, my application had 1.4 GB of memory usage, so I started searching for a solution.
Knowing that I am using MVVM in my application, I’m using data and command binding, my views are properly closed using window.close() command defined in the metro mahapps windows.

I used ANTS Memory Profiler to find the source of the leak and I took a memory snapshot when my application memory usage was at 1.35 GB.
After analysis, the instances kept in memory are System.Byte[] types and the path to the GC root is :
System.Byte[] ==> System.IO.MemoryStream ==> System.Windows.Baml2006.SharedStream ==> System.Windows.Baml2006.BamlBinaryReader ==> System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader ==> System.Windows.ResourceDictionnary ==> System.Windows.ResourceDictionnary[] ==> List ==> ResourceDictionaryCollection ==> ResourceDictionary ==> System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry[] ==> MyView

I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Autofac or other IOC container?

Comment: No @helmsb , i'm not

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue with a .net 4.0 project. Back then it was a known issue with the Workflow Designer. I had thought that the issue had been resolved in .net 4.5 but maybe this old solution could be of some use.

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128214/wpf-wf4-5-rehosted-designer-memory-issues) allows you to marshal the workflow designer in its own app domain. So it's effectively allowing you to load the designer using AppDomain Isolated WPF Add-Ins.

This certainly removed the memory leak in question for me that was occurring in our re-hosted solution.